# How can I change pantheon-files folder marking colors?

Tags: gnome, gtk3, pantheon

I am using arc theme on Ubuntu 18.04. I installed pantheon files as a file manager. Then I set theme to arc dark but in dark mode pantheon-files folder marking color doesn't look normal. I want to edit this colors.

[image]